# Удалить элемент из массива в mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Подскажите пожалуйста как составить правильно запрос на удаление элемента из массива в mongodb.

В mongodb есть примерно такая структура:

```
user: {
    ...,
    friendIds: [
        "635928ad765fc4734ef6e590",
        "6123123765fc4734efc6e11d",
        ...
    ]
}
```

Пытаюсь составить запрос чтобы удалить из массива нужны ID, код ниже

```
const res = this.UserModel.remove({
    $pull: { friendIds: "635928ad765fc4734ef6e590" },
})
```

Но наверное что-то составил не правильно, и запрос не работает. По хорошему должно получится

```
user: {
    ...,
    friendIds: [
        "6123123765fc4734efc6e11d",
        ...
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

На примере такого JSON и операции updateOne в mongodb.. Необходимо указывать _id документа..

```js
{
    "_id" : "document_id",
    "m" : [ "1", "2", "3", "4"],
    "obj" : {
        "m" : [ "1", "2", "3", "4"],
        "pref" : 5
    }
}
//удалит элемент массива с значением 2 из документа с id 'document_id' в поле m
db.getCollection('name').updateOne({_id:'document_id'},{$pull:{"m": '2' }});

//удалит элемент массива с значением 3 из документа с id 'document_id' в поле obj.m
db.getCollection('name').updateOne({_id:'document_id'},{$pull:{"obj.m": '3' }});
```